# sql select statement using a FUNCTION without access to the SQL DB in .Net

Tags: .net, sql, function, select

i have a SQL DB that only have reader permissions, as so i cant add my only stored proc or functions, and i am looking for a way to complete my mission without getting admin permission (the software only have reader permissions for developers and does not allow full access, that is why I am looking for another way)

What I have is a table that i want to pull records from, but to do this there is a need to do some calculations on the fields to work out lengths.

is there a way in .Net or using an SQL script file that i can run that will accomplish this?
Not sure if I need to do all thoughts to get the required results
-create a temp table
-insert into temp table fields from a table AND the calculated value
-WHERE calculated value is less than 100

(now i can do it using CREATE statements but this is no good, as above, there is no DB access to create anything.. so it needs to be some type of dynamic code that cant do both select and functions in one)

here is a sample of the SQL code of what I am typing to get working in .Net code

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #Listings
(
AddressID varchar(50), Street varchar(50), City varchar(50), State varchar(50), 
    Zip varchar(50), ZipCalculatedValue Decimal(18,12)
)
INSERT INTO #Listings (AddressID, Street, City, State, Zip, ZipCalculatedValue)
SELECT AddressID, Street, City, State, Zip, Name, bo.CalcZip(@ZIP) AS ZipCalculatedValue
FROM tbl_Addresses
WHERE dbo.dbo.CalcZip(@ZIP) <= @maxZIP
ORDER BY Distance ASC

SELECT * 
FROM #Listings
```

and the function looks like

```
  DECLARE @ZIP FLOAT

  SET @ZIPCalc = (@ZIP - 1000) --more code but removed to simplify

  SET @ZIPCalc = (@ZIPCalc * 10) --result above more workings removed

  RETURN @ZIPCalc
```

so in .Net i can connect to the DB and get results, but any idea on how I can use a FUNCTION with a SELECT statement to pull results?

thanks

Comment: Can you do you calculation for max zip in another SQL call and then pass that to your original sql select?

Comment: Hi Paddy.. but how do i include the FUNCTION within the select statement so that its part of the return set.. its the FUNCTION part of the sql working that im stuck with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to calculate the value.

```
WITH AddressWithCalc AS
(
    SELECT AddressID, Street, City, State, Zip,
        ((@ZIP - 1000) * 10) AS ZipCalculatedValue
    FROM dbo.tbl_Addresses
)
INSERT INTO #Listings (AddressID, Street, City, State, Zip, ZipCalculatedValue)
SELECT *
FROM AddressWithCalc
WHERE ZipCalculatedValue <= @maxZIP
ORDER BY Distance ASC
```

Comment: Genius.. thanks Anthony, had to tweak a little as i dont think i could use the create temp table part, but with a little modification i have it working :)